# [ckeditor]: How to disallow only one css style

Tags: ckeditor, config, ckeditor4.x

Hy,

is there any way to disallow only

> display: inline-block; and display: block;

and allow other display rules? If I add *{display*} to the config.disallowedContent rules all display styles will not be allowed (also display table, inline and others).

Tnx for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) to filter style property values but [`CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor) gives you some handful interface ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/dwjh932n/)):

```
var filterDisplayProperty = {
    attributes: {
        style: function( value, element ) {
            value = CKEDITOR.tools.parseCssText( value, 1 );

            if ( value.display in { 'block': 1, 'inline-block': 1 } ) {
                delete value.display;
            }

            // If there's no CSS rules left, discard style attribute.
            return CKEDITOR.tools.writeCssText( value ) || false;
        }    
    }
};

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    toolbar: [ [ 'Source' ], [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ], [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline' ], [ 'CreateDiv' ] ],
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function() {
            // Filter data that comes INTO the editor.
            this.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( filterDisplayProperty ); 

            // Filter data that comes OUT of the editor.
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( filterDisplayProperty );
        }
    }    
} );
```